# Flutter Tab Bar on Tap Page change is not happening

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to use tab bar and Tabbarview. It should change the page by sliding left and right and also by tapping the tab bar. But taping is not changing the tabbarview pages.
I have tried using the expanded widget but it's still not working. Can anyone tell me what is causing the problem?
Here is my code:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 360.0,
            child: ClipPath(
              clipper: MyCliper(),
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 360.0,
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: TabBar(
                    controller: _tabController,
                    tabs: const [
                      Tab(text: 'Tab 1'),
                      Tab(text: 'Tab 2'),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: TabBarView(
                    controller: _tabController,
                    children: const [
                      Center(child: Text('Tab 1 Content')),
                      Center(child: Text('Tab 2 Content')),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyCliper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    var path = Path();
    path.lineTo(0, size.height);
    final firstCurve = Offset(0, size.height - 20);
    final lastCurve = Offset(30, size.height - 20);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(
        firstCurve.dx, firstCurve.dy, lastCurve.dx, lastCurve.dy);
    final secondFirstCurve = Offset(0, size.height - 20);
    final secondLastCurve = Offset(size.width - 30, size.height - 20);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(secondFirstCurve.dx, secondFirstCurve.dy,
        secondLastCurve.dx, secondLastCurve.dy);
    final thirdFirstCurve = Offset(size.width, size.height - 20);
    final thirdLastCurve = Offset(size.width, size.height);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(thirdFirstCurve.dx, thirdFirstCurve.dy,
        thirdLastCurve.dx, thirdLastCurve.dy);
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

My page screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that you are using an Expanded widget for both the TabBar and the TabBarView. The Expanded widget should be placed within a Column or Row to allow its children to expand within the available space. In your case, the Expanded widgets are placed within a Stack, which might not be letting them expand as intended.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 360.0,
            child: ClipPath(
              clipper: MyClipper(),
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                TabBar(
                  controller: _tabController,
                  tabs: const [
                    Tab(text: 'Tab 1'),
                    Tab(text: 'Tab 2'),
                  ],
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: TabBarView(
                    controller: _tabController,
                    children: const [
                      Center(child: Text('Tab 1 Content')),
                      Center(child: Text('Tab 2 Content')),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

1. Wrap with `DefaultTabController`

   ```
    class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
      const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return DefaultTabController(
          length: 2,
          child: Scaffold(
            body: Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: 360.0,
                  child: ClipPath(
                    clipper: MyCliper(),
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 360.0,
                  child: Stack(
                    children: [
                      Column(
                        children: [
                          TabBar(
                            tabs: const [
                              Tab(text: 'Tab 1'),
                              Tab(text: 'Tab 2'),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: TabBarView(
                              children: const [
                                Center(child: Text('Tab 1 Content')),
                                Center(child: Text('Tab 2 Content')),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
   ```

   }